# JOIN with an IF condition?

Tags: mysql, join

I have my main table and I have 2 tables that will be joined. I want to join table A if the employee is a male and table B if the employee is a female. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What about using two SQL clauses and dispatching of the logic before the SQL statements?

Comment: Do you *really* want separate tables here and not a combined table with a `gender` column?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
  SELECT ....
  FROM main JOIN A ON ...
  WHERE male
UNION ALL
  SELECT ....
  FROM main JOIN B ON ...
  WHERE female
```

Comment: That returns:

#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

SELECT * FROM `spells` JOIN `spells_weaken` ON `spells`.`id` = `spells_weaken`.`spell_id` WHERE `spells`.`type` = 7 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `spells` JOIN `spells_damage` ON `spells`.`id` = `spells_damage`.`spell_id` WHERE `spells`.`type` = 2;

Answer (score 1):

You can still join both tables, but use `CASE` statement to decide which table to read from.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Table.Field = 'Male' THEN A.Field ELSE B.Field END AS Something
  FROM Table
  LEFT JOIN A on condition
  LEFT JOIN B on condition
```

Comment: You probably need LEFT JOINs because the "male" records will likely not match anything in the "wrong" join table.

Comment: I'm not really understanding how to use this. I used the other answers query, could you modify it to use your approach so I understand it more please? ELECT * FROM spells JOIN spells_weaken ON spells.id = spells_weaken.spell_id WHERE spells.type = 7 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM spells JOIN spells_damage ON spells.id = spells_damage.spell_id WHERE spells.type = 2;

Comment: What field(s) are you wanting to pull from the related table?  If the two tables (or desired result sets) don't have the same number of fields then there's no point in pulling them in a single query.